# If my base currency is INR and want to checkout with AUD using paypal express checkout which currency is shown in paypal confirmaiton

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

If my base currency is INR and want to checkout with AUD using paypal express checkout which currency is shown in paypal payment confirmation page.

Answer (score 2):

PayPal wouldn't work with base currency INR. you must define AUD as base currency. Or there are certain extensions available in Magento store which helps you to checkout using AUD with INR base currency.